# ndk-stack.exe just show "Segmentation fault"

Tags: c++, android-ndk, segmentation-fault, g++, cocos2d-x

I program a game with cocos2d-x. In some case my game crashes.
I use "ndk-stack" to find crash point, but the ndk-stack just show "Segmentation fault". How can I get more information about the cause of crash?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could't find any other solution for this problem when ndk-stack just show `"segmentation fault"`. The only solution is you should save logcat data in a file, then manually find this pattern. `"*** *** *** ..."`
From there,until the end of file, you can find some good information about classes and functions.
here is my information. I found this line about 200 line later than above pattern.

```
I/DEBUG   ( 8175):     #02  pc 007a0e40  /data/app-lib/com.Lotus.Footcardia-1/libcocos2dcpp.so (rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator> >::FindMember(char const*)+128)
```

it say the problem is from the rapidjsonand I know where i use rapidjson.

The bad news is that the size of log file increase rapidly.

Comment: Of course, the size of the logfile is less relevant as it is kept on the PC, not the Android device.

Comment: @Klaas van Gend: You are right. I mean loading a huge file with text editor like notepad++ is a little difficult.